# symfony 4 easyadmin add association field and select other field in this entity

Tags: symfony, easyadmin

I want to use a field in an entity that is linked in another entity that I use in my controller. I use easyadmin 3 and symfony 4. How to make an AssociationField in this condition? Can someone give me a hand? thanks

Example:
In a "payment" table, there is a "debt_id" field (related to the payment table).
And in the "debt" table, I want to select another field (for example, the paid field).

Answer (score 0):

Let's say that you added in your **payment CrudController** a field like that:

`AssociationField::new('debt_id'),`

So now you should add this code in your **Debt Entity**:

```
public function __toString(): string
{
  return $this->yourPaidField;   
}
```